# UIImagePicker crash on iPad IOS5

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

does anybody see what's wrong with this code?

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceType pickerType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

[imagePicker setSourceType:pickerType];
[imagePicker setMediaTypes:[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:pickerType]];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];

UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100) inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];
```

On ios4 it works well. But on ios5/ipad it crashes with

```
*** Assertion failure in -[PLHighlightingTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:6072
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

The exception occurs when I scroll the image picker.

Any ideas?

Regards

-dezember

Comment: I think i found the problem: `[pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500)];` seems to be the problem. Without this line it doesn't crash. Now the question is: Is this a bug in iOS 5?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful since it's not the exact problem you describe, but I've found that the certain calls to setPopoverContentSize: result in different display sizes in IOS 4 vs. iOS 5...which is of course, very frustrating. Like I said, not necessarily helpful, except that it suggests that changes were made to that method in iOS 5. My vote: probably a bug.